# publish asp.net website into single dll file

Tags: asp.net

I got a asp.net website from my client that need to be modified. The problem is that the old company was uploading the project as a release which means no code but a sinlge dll file.

We can make a single dll file the project type is web application not a website!!

Can you adivse how to publish sinlgle dll fiel.

Regards,

Moayyad

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single DLL, then **convert your website into a web application**. Once you convert, everything inside your project will be compiled into a single DLL file.But still, any external assemblies will be inside their own DLL files.

Comment: How to convert, and is it recommended?

Comment: If you want your website compiled into a single dll then you have to convert to web application. here's the link : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/10/29/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project.aspx